# CLion static analysis false errors

Tags: c++, clion, static-code-analysis

I am using CLion IDE. Recent times very often IDE display false errors. Howerer same code compiles successfully.
For example:

[image: screenshot]

False error not fixes after reopen project and restart IDE.
Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like the include file was not found. This looks like your CMake macro for detecting the include files doesn't work correctly.

Your project still compiles, because most likely the include files are installed into the standard include path (e.g. /usr/include/ on Linux) of your compiler.

Comment: No, this is one of the many errors of the static analyzer. For example, it happens that when you include a header "filesystem". Static analyzer not detects std::filesystem namespace (C++17), but code compiles successfully.

Comment: The problem disappears after some time, maybe half an hour

Answer (score 0):

CMake tool window / refresh icon.

[image].

When subdirectries are added for includes and / or code, cmake needs to be re-run to adapt CLion's internal project structure.